# Como filtrar multiples valores de una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

| ID | CODE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 447731 | BAR | 11 |
| 447731 | SUS | 4 |
| 446850 | BAR | 4 |
| 446850 | SUS | 11 |
| 446848 | SUS | 4 |
| 446848 | SUS | 11 |
| 446848 | BAR | 11 |
| 446848 | BAR | 11 |
| 446846 | BAR | 11 |
| 446846 | SUS | 4 |
| 446845 | BAR | 4 |
| 446845 | SUS | 4 |
| 446844 | SUS | 11 |
| 446844 | BAR | 11 |

Partiendo de la base que es una unica tabla. Como seleccionar la combinacion de BAR = 4 y SUS = 11
El resultado esperado seria ID = 446850, que es el unico ID con esa combinacion, utilizando SQL Developer

Comment: ¿Cuál es la llave primaria de la tabla? `SELECT DISTINCT ID WHERE (CODE = 'BAR' AND STATUS=4) OR  (CODE = 'SUS' AND STATUS=11) `

Comment: te acabo de poner la solucion con enlace para que lo ejecutes espero que te sirva y @JaimeMenéndez creo qe te falta el ``SELECT .... FROM suTabla .... ``no?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya tienes toda la razón. Olvidé poner el nombre de la tabla, me centré solamente en las condiciones y olvidé eso. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Nunca respondiste lo de la llave primaria. Quiero pensar que eso es una tabla intermedia y no una entidad de tu base de datos porque si no estaría bien mal diseñada. Ten en cuenta que este tipo de consultas se accede con un join desde la tabla a la que pertenece el id, no tiene sentido hacer una consulta a una tabla intermedia para luego “virar para atrás”. Pero bueno, los pocos detalles que adjuntas no dejan lugar para respuestas que valgan la pena.

Comment: si te vale no te olvides de marcar con el check para que se resuelva

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez no hay de que mi respuesta la acabo de modificar espero que le sirva

Comment: no te olvides de esto : https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Con el IN se puede hacer que se cumpla las dos como en este ejemplo, entonces filtro por `CODE IN('BAR','SUS')` las cuales se cumplen ambas y lo mismo con `STATUS IN(4,11)`.

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE CODE IN('BAR','SUS') AND STATUS IN(4,11);
```

**Ejecutar Prueba :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/132

**Otra    Prueba :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/131

Comment: Javier gracias por la respuesta! El tema es que en un universo de datos mas grandes la query tambien trae los ID que tienen o BAR=11 o STATUS=4. Tendrian que cumplirse ambas condiciones correlativas. Tiene que existir el BAR=4 y tambien debe cumplir con el STATUS=11 para un ID

Comment: vale pues espera y lo modifico

Comment: @JavierG.Raya tu respuesta esta genial (+1),, tanto la nueva edición como la anterior (puedes incluir las dos si gustas). Reproduciste su planteamiento y todo. Es la pregunta la que no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: muchas gracias @JaimeMenéndez prefiero dejarlo asi, toma la URL  de lo anterior : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/130

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución es filtrar primero los registros que cumplen con las condiciones que buscas y luego filtrar aquellos que cumplen con las dos.

```
WITH base as (
  SELECT id 
  FROM   cliente 
  WHERE 
     (code = 'BAR' AND status=4) OR 
     (code = 'SUS' AND status=11)
)
SELECT id
FROM base
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa un `JOIN` sobre la misma tabla:

```sql
SELECT c1.id 
FROM CLIENTE c1
JOIN CLIENTE c2 ON 
  c1.id = c2.id AND 
  c1.code = 'BAR' AND c1.status = 4 AND 
  c2.code = 'SUS' AND c2.status = 11
```